# Listbox selection does not go up or down the list when arrow button pressed

Tags: wpf, xaml

Why Listbox jumps from last record to first when I press up or down arrow key once?

Here is how to reproduce this problem

MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListbox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}" />
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        MyListbox.Focus();
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Entities = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "Batman",
            "Superman",
            "Shrek",
            "Jack Frost",
            "Wolverine"
        };
        SelectedEntity = Entities.Last();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Entities { get; set; }

    private string selectedEntity;
    public string SelectedEntity
    {
        get { return selectedEntity; }
        set { OnPropertyChanged(ref selectedEntity, value); }
    }
}
```

I found this problem in a large application and I managed to reproduce it in isolation in the above code, so when the window appears Listbox will have last item selected, if I press up arrow key it jumps to the first item no to a previous one.
I tried `Mode TwoWay`, `UpdateSourceTriggerPropertyChange` etc on this couple of lines of XAML, but nothing worked.

It only happens at the begining once it jumps to the top it then behaves as it should, if I grab a mouse and click on the item and then use keyboard it also works.

Comment: Since I'm not sure and have no time to test just leaving as a comment, but you might try `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation=Cycle` since Continue is default and it's saying "oh, you're on the last one, you obviously want to jump back to the first right?" more or less. Worth a quick shot, either way I'll swing back, we're in the middle of struggling with a ton of keyboard scenarios with ListBox also.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you for your comment, however it does not fix this issue. What happens is, when I'm on the last one and I press Up Arrow it also jumps to the first one, if I was in the middle, then does not matter whether I press Up or Down it will jump to the first one :(, but only for the first time, after that it works as expected. The suggestion you gave answered a different question I had :) Lots of keyboard issues here as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because when you set focus to list box it dosent set focus to selected item, use this code to set focus to item as well..

```
<ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"></Setter>                    </Trigger>  
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

Comment: Having to do stuff like this really makes me wonder what Microsoft was thinking when they decided that WPF was ready to be released.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that setting IsTabStop="False" to ListBoxItem causes the same behavior you have reported.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It took me an hour to figure out...